# Difference between KMC Z6 and Z7 for 6 speed cassete?

Tags: chain

What is the difference between **KMC Z6** and **KMC Z7** for 6 speed cassete?

On KMC site, both of them appear to be suitable for 6 speed bike.

**KMC Z7**:
https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/il/en/kmc-z7-7-speed-chain/rp-prod51830

**KMC Z6**:
https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/il/en/kmc-z6-6-speed-chain/rp-prod193013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z6:[image]
 <sup>from http://kmcchain.us/chain/z6-br-gy/</sup>

Z7:[image]
 <sup>from http://kmcchain.us/chain/z7-2/</sup>

I think the only real difference is colour: Z6 is "silver" Z7 is "grey/brown"  This is important to some people.

Note, Z6 was renamed from Z33, and Z7 was formerly called Z50.

I think your links show the wrong image for Z6 - the KMC site shows plain chain without slots, so CRC have a bad image.

Comment: On this page it shows chamfering for the Z6 which would probably make it lighter: https://www.kmcchain.com/en/product/bicycle-chain-z6-6-speed
The different colours could be an indication of a different alloy, but not sure which one is better.

Comment: @Michael the KMC site shows both have "chamfered internal plates"  Given these are sub $10 USD or sub 5 UKP chains, they're not exactly high end.

Comment: Interesting, but only the Z6 photo on the linked (by me) page actually shows chamfered plates.

Comment: Does **narrow** label on Z7 chain has any meaning?

Comment: @MichaelD I think that just means its 3/32" chain, instead of wider 1/8" chain.   Both are 3/32" derailleur chain for 6~7 speed bikes.